# Can't change self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using TWTSideMenuViewController.

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate=self;
[self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(openMenu)];

-(void)openMenu{
[self.sideMenuViewController openMenuAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

The problem is, I only want it to open in the root viewController.

Anywhere else in my navigation stack, it should pop to the previous viewController.

I've tried setting the other viewController as the interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate when it appears and registering it to @selector(popToViewController:) , 
but it's still popping my side menu open, in addition to popping back to the previous VC.

I've tried `self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate=nil;`

when my rootViewController disappear, and it's still popping the side menu open.